# Why are the lights fuzzy/hazy/blowing out in my pictures?

Tags: lens, sensor, lights

I just got a Canon 70D off eBay and have been taking night pictures and things were ok. Then, without warning, the lights in my pictures got blurry and hazy, maybe overblown. It's happened with both my lenses. 50mm and 28-135mm.  We don't have a good camera store nearby.  I have no idea where to start.  Please help?

[image]

Comment: Is it the [lens flare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_flare) what you talking about? Or is it just [overexposure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exposure_(photography)#Overexposure_and_underexposure)?

Comment: Most of the time, the cause for hazy lights is...haze.

Comment: I am going to guess that it is over exposure that he is talking about...but he posted no exif data so we really have no way to offer any suggestions...

Comment: Atmospheric haze...the photographic equivalent of the earth throwing a middle finger at every would be landscape photographer.

Comment: I don't see any problem with your photo. some over and under exposure areas and some reflected light that are quite normal in that situation generally.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! It was a crystal clear night and it wasn't hazy at all. I took a pic with my iPhone to compare and it was clear, showed the detail of the moon. Could it be the sensor, lens or a setting? I'm not sure where/if I could upload another pic showing this happening with the street lights too.

Answer (score 4):

It might have been slight condensation on the lens if it was perfectly fine and then "without warning" things got hazy. I don't know what the temperature /humidity was like but on clear nights things exposed to the night sky can cool by radiating their heat to said sky. If the temperature falls below the dew point condensation will form. This is a known phenomena for astrophotographers and astronomers. Try it again on a clear night that's relatively warm and dry (or an overcast night) and see if it repeats.

Answer (score 0):

Dirty lens produces softening effect on bright objects. Just make sure to use a special cloth if you clean it.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with your aperture. If you close down your lens to a narrow aperture you will get a sharper crisper edges to the lights and even a star like effect. If you widen your aperture you will get a soft glow like in your picture. Take the same picture at f/16 or f/22 and the softness will go, take it at f/2.8 and your haziness will return.